# VS Code editor strikes through .click() function text #jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code

Why does VS Code editor show jQuery .click() function as strike-through formatted text?

[image]

Comment: Have you "JQuery Intellisense" installed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"click()" is deprecated since jQuery version 3.3, you can use "on('click', cb)".

If you hover it, you will get this:

[image]